# Как поочередно менять цвет объекта при попадании в тригер?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Не понимаю как правильно задать условие что бы оно срабатывало один раз, а не меняло быстро с белого на черный. Тригер нужно обязательно пересекать.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ColorChange : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D Trigger) {
        if (Trigger.tag == "Player")
        {
            if(Trigger.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color == Color.black)
            {
                Trigger.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.white;
                Debug.Log("+");
            }
            else if(Trigger.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color == Color.white)
            {   
                Trigger.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.black;
                Debug.Log("-");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Консоль при одном нажатии на пробел:
[image: Debug.Log]

Здесь как выглядит самоприложение:
[image: Тригер]

Редактор Player:

[image: Player]

Редактор Trigger:

[image: Trigger]

Comment: Где то может два коллайдера на игроке или триггере, может скрипт дважды висит ? Сделай тогда скрины редактора, что бы были видны коллайдеры. Добавь еще OnTriggerExit2D с логами, вдруг он выходит-> заходит -> и снова выходит, но делает это быстро, так что нельзя заметить

Comment: Изменил понял что есть на игроке еще тригер, он используется что бы игрок мог использовать пробел только когда стоит на платформе.

Comment: В консоле два входа,два выхода , а на игроке два коллайдера, убери один  и попробуй. "Изменил понял что есть на игроке еще тригер" - если он нужен, то перемести в дочерний объект игрока, и измени дочернему объекту tag

Comment: Я только недавно занялся Unity и я не знаю как переместить в дочерний объект игрока.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ZDZaKrofmc

Comment: Я добавил дочерний объект, поместил в игрока добавил коллайдер ничего не меняя все сразу заработало. Огромное спасибо, я уже 2 день не мог разобраться в этом.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D Trigger) {
    if (Trigger.tag == "Player")
    {
        if(Trigger.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color == Color.black)
        {
            Trigger.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.white;
        }

        else if(Trigger.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color == Color.white)
        {   
            Trigger.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.black;
        }
    }
}
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else

Comment: Нет это не помогает, я уже пробовал

Comment: относительно кода в вопросе, это решение. Значит есть еще проблемы, но по дугой причине, может он пересекает сразу два объекта

Comment: Объект перемещается сверху вниз на пробел(меняя гравитацию), и на пути у него всегда стоит 1 тригер, и когда он его пересекает он меняет цвет в одну сторону на черный, в другую сторону на белый.

Comment: 1. Ты точно попробовал мой ответ? 2. Попробуй вставить в функцию логи и посмотреть что не так.3. Приложи скрины, гиф или видео

Comment: Я добавил все в сам вопрос